# Need help configuring inbound access from the internet into my local LAN

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a LTE connection to the internet through a Huawei B315s-936 router.
It's internal IP Address is 10.0.0.1, with DHCP configured to start allocating addresses from 10.0.0.3
I can also ping this router's public IP Address from an external computer fine.

This router only has one device connected to it, a NETGEAR R6400 WiFi Router.

The Netgear's internet setup is configured as a static IP address 10.0.0.2, with it's gateway configured as 10.0.0.1
The Netgear's LAN setup is configured with internal IP Address 192.168.1.1 and has DHCP configured to start allocating addresses from 192.168.1.4

ALL other network devices in my home connect to this NETGEAR router, and have addresses in the 192.168.1 range.

Outgoing internet access work fine from all devices.

Now I have a service running on a server that I would like to access when I am away from home. This service is accessed locally via a web browser on local address 192.168.1.15:799

So what I have done is to configure the Virtual Server settings on the Huawei Router as follows:
[image: Huawei Router Virtual Server Config]

On my Netgear Router I have configured Port Forwarding as follows:
[image: Netgear Port Forwarding Config]

Yet, when I point a web browser at [huawei router public ip addess]:799, the browser returns an Unable to Connect message (it's not a 404 not found response...it's just a no-response at all)

What I find interesting is that if I configure the Netgear Router's logging to log Port-Forwarding events, I can see the following entries that indicate that the router is receiving the requests:

[LAN access from remote] from [ip address of remote computer]:37238 to 192.168.1.15:799, Thursday, Sep 14,2017 08:08:06

[LAN access from remote] from [ip address of remote computer]:37237 to 192.168.1.15:799, Thursday, Sep 14,2017 08:08:06

[LAN access from remote] from [ip address of remote computer]:37433 to 192.168.1.15:799, Thursday, Sep 14,2017 08:05:40

[LAN access from remote] from [ip address of remote computer]:37432 to 192.168.1.15:799, Thursday, Sep 14,2017 08:05:40

Note the port of the FROM address is incrementing for some reason, but it does show that the destination of the request is the expected internal ip address and port.  This tells me that the Netgear Router is receiving the request from the Huawei Router.

Please help me understand what I am missing here to get this working?

Thanks,
--Shawn.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like your server 192.168.1.15:799 is behind two NAT routers. The outside NAT router ist your Huawei, and looks like it works like it should, because you can see access attempts in your Netgear's log. So I take for granted, that it works up to that point.

Next Steps might be the following:

- Using `tcpdump -n port 799 on your 192.168.1.15:799 server, check if you see anything coming in. Also try from a PC or notebook on 192.168.1.xxx to reach your server on port 799.
- Plug in a notebook instead of Huawei, configure it to 10.0.0.1 and try to connect to 10.0.0.2:779. Your netgear should log it just as before, and I guess you again won't reach your server. You'll have to redo your Netgear configuration until it works.
- You might want to disable NAT on your Netgear, so you can simply route packtes from Huawei straight to your server; no more port forwarding necessary on Netgear; Huawei would have to forward to 192.168.1.15:799 directly.

Comment: Thanks @TomTomTom I am away from home for a while but will try these as soon as I get back!